# Fill Jenkins extended choice parameter with values from a CSV file using groovy script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I need to get data from a csv file placed in the same server that Jenkins, the idea is to fill the parameter with values from that file, in this case, IP addresses. Also I want to check if Jenkins is reaching the file or not (permissions or something else)

I tried with a simple groovy script using **readCSV** plugin inside of a extended-choice-parameter, but it didn't works...

```
readCSV file: '/var/lib/jenkins/ips.csv'.each { line ->
    line.each { field ->
        return field
    }
```

File example:

```
0.0.0.0;1.1.1.1
```

I can install additional plugins in Jenkins if necessary

Comment: Already tried examples from this site? https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/

Comment: Not all but some of them, I was thinking that maybe I’m not reaching the file because of I’m in a different workspace...